# display image in jsp file Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Success page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <img alt="Preview not available" src="/images/photo.jpg" /><br /><br />



</body>
</html>
```

springs-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="co" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources location="/images/**" mapping="/images/" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springs" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="medusa" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="5000"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="jt" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

         <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />

    </bean>


</beans>
```

[image: Application Structure]

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>FileUploading02</groupId>
  <artifactId>FileUploading02</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have seen that this particular question is being asked a lot here and provided solution had worked for many, but when I applied that solution which is adding 
 tag to my Spring-servlet, still no luck. When I run my success page on a server it shows me the alternate text of the image. Moreover, the images are static which is kept inside my application only.

Comment: try to add your war_name :                                                                         <img alt="Preview not available" src="<your_war_name>/images/photo.jpg" />

Comment: nope, it is not working.

Comment: could you paste your url here?

Comment: which url do you want ??

Comment: your image url...

Comment: file:///E:/Prakhar/STS%20Workspace/CreatingSpringProjects/FileUploading02/WebContent/images/photo.jpg

Comment: what is your war file name?                                                                                 and try to access http://localhost:8080/<your_War_file_name>/images/photo.jp‌​g

Comment: FileUploading02  maybe......how to check the war file name??

Comment: hit http://localhost:8080/FileUploading02/images/photo.jp‌​g and tell me the output.

Comment: it is showing me error code 404

Comment: to know about your war file then post your pom.xml file

Comment: <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>FileUploading02</groupId>
  <artifactId>FileUploading02</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

Comment: Please try sample hello world program of spring mvc  in the web and comeback  to this application. you need to learn more about it.

Comment: my hello world programs are working just fine...in this example i was doing file uploading. I successfully uploaded the file on the server to my desired location then i wanted to display it on one of the page, that is what i failed to do. So i tried to show a static image which resides inside my application but i am not able to display images on my jsp.

Answer (score 0):

changes in documents

springs-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**" />
```

success.jsp

```
<img alt="Preview not available" src="/FileUploading02/images/photo.jpg" />
```

i solved it by adding these two changes.

Thanks VNT for your time.